# Why is UnobservedTaskException thrown despite the observation when using async await?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

The following scenario runs under *.NET 4.5* so any `UnobservedTaskException` does not [terminate the process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have the habit of listening to any `UnobservedTaskException` thrown by having this execute at the start of my app:

```
private void WatchForUnobservedTaskExceptions()
{
  TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
  {
      args.Exception.Dump("Ooops");
  };
}
```

I also have a helper method for when I want to *explicitly* ignore any exceptions thrown by my tasks:

```
public static Task IgnoreExceptions(Task task) 
  => task.ContinueWith(t =>
      {
          var ignored = t.Exception.Dump("Checked");
      },
      CancellationToken.None,
      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
      TaskScheduler.Default);
```

So if I have the following code execute:

```
void Main()
{
  WatchForUnobservedTaskExceptions();

  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
  });

  IgnoreExceptions(task);

  GC.Collect(2);
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

  Console.ReadLine();    
}
```

After we return from the `Console.ReadLine()` we will not see any `UnobservedTaskException` thrown which is what we expect.

However if I change the above `task` to start using `async/await` with everything else the same as before:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
});
```

Now we get the `UnobservedTaskException` thrown. Debugging the code reveals the continuation executes with the  `t.Exception` being `null`.

How can I ignore the exceptions properly in both scenarios?

Comment: Why not catch the exception in your async function.  Then you wouldn't get an unobserved task exception.

Comment: The point of the helper method is to avoid having to do the catch everywhere.

Comment: How realistic is this scenario anyway? You shouldn't wrap an already async method in `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: FWIW: I don't see the exception; but ... what is your `Dump()` method here? any chance it is `[Conditional]` ? I wonder if just using `GC.KeepAlive(args.Exception)` and `GC.KeepAlive(t.Exception)` (respectively) would be better - note: `GC.KeepAlive` doesn't *do* anything - it is just an opaque method that guarantees not to be erased by the JIT

Comment: @PeterBons oh, there are uses for that, to be fair; not always good uses, but sometimes

Comment: Try `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. It works then on my machine

Comment: @MarcGravell  `Dump()` is a method of [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}).Unwrap();
```

or

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
});
```

See [this blogpost about Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) about using Task.Factory.StartNew with async modifiers

> By using the async keyword here, the compiler is going to map this delegate to be a `Func<Task<int>>`: invoking the delegate will return the `Task<int>` to represent the eventual completion of this call.  And since the delegate is `Func<Task<int>>`, `TResult` is `Task<int>`, and thus the type of ‘t’ is going to be `Task<Task<int>>`, not `Task<int>`.
>
> To handle these kinds of cases, in .NET 4 we introduced the Unwrap method.

Some more [background](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

> **Why Not to Use Task.Factory.StartNew?**
>
> .. Does not understand async delegates. … . The problem is that when you pass an async delegate to StartNew, it’s natural to assume that the returned task represents that delegate. However, since StartNew does not understand async delegates, what that task actually represents is just the beginning of that delegate. This is one of the first pitfalls that coders encounter when using StartNew in async code.

**EDIT**

The type of `task` in `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async (...))` => is actually `Task<Task<int>>`. You have to `Unwrap` that to get the source task. With that in mind:

You can only call `Unwrap` on a `Task<Task>>` so you could add an overload to  `IgnoreExceptions` to accommodate that:

```
void Main()
{
    WatchForUnobservedTaskExceptions();

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    });

    IgnoreExceptions(task);

    GC.Collect(2);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void WatchForUnobservedTaskExceptions()
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.Exception.Dump("Ooops");
    };
}

public static Task IgnoreExceptions(Task task)
  => task.ContinueWith(t =>
      {
          var ignored = t.Exception.Dump("Checked");
      },
      CancellationToken.None,
      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
      TaskScheduler.Default);


public static Task IgnoreExceptions(Task<Task> task)
=> task.Unwrap().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var ignored = t.Exception.Dump("Checked");
},
CancellationToken.None,
TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: `Task.Run()` is not an option as the `IgnoreExceptions` lives in a library and oblivious to where the `task` is coming from. I cannot seem to use the `Unwrap` in `IgnoreException`, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `var` and `Task` and `Task<T>`'s interited relationship, masks the problem. If I rewrite the code slightly, it will become obvious where the problem is.

```
  Task<int> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     throw new InvalidOperationException();
     return 1;
  });

  Task<Task<int>> task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
  {
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     throw new InvalidOperationException();
     return 1;
  });
```

This better illustrates what Peter Bons is talking about.

Comment: Thank you, this helps illustrate the problem much better.